# Increase Length of Stream Data from Client to Sharepoint Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, json

I am trying to update a column in a SharePoint 2013 Custom list but I am getting this error

> The maximum number of bytes allowed to be read from the stream has been exceeded. After the last read operation, a total of 1049600 bytes has been read from the stream; however a maximum of 1048576 bytes is allowed.

I am doing this operation using JSON & jQuery POST Method.

How can I increase this limit of 1MB (1048576 Bytes)?

Comment: What is the type of your column?

Comment: @LeopoldLerch Colum Type is **Multiple Lines of Text** with Number of Line for Editing: **1000** and Type of Text allow : **Plain Text**

Comment: I too have ran into this issue, is there any update ?